# The Battle of Britain

Tags: world-war-two, britain

During the [Battle of Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Britain) were there any battles on British land or were they all up in the air?  If there were no battles on land, why did the Nazis never [cross the channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Sea_Lion)?

Comment: These questions are covered by the linked wikipedia pages.

Comment: You should do some preliminary research before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

The Battle of Britain was a battle to gain control over the airspace over the channel and the English coast. Control of the airspace would have enabled Germany to control the English Channel sea zone because the German Navy was considerably weaker than the British but air superiority would have enabled the German Navy to prevail and cover a crossing of the channel for the army.

The Nazis lost the Battle of Britain, never gaining air superiority. As a direct result they never controlled the English Channel and as a direct result of that, never crossed it successfully with any land troops.

Comment: Indeed, they never *tried* to move troops across. They knew they'd fail without air superiority.